# How to iterate through all views of all modules added to Unity catalog

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a modular WPF/Prism/Unity application.
Modules are added to the catalog in the App code like

```
protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
{
    moduleCatalog.AddModule<ModuleA>();
    moduleCatalog.AddModule<ModuleB>();
    moduleCatalog.AddModule<ModuleC>();
}
```

Each module has few Views - UserControls. I want to add an interface to some of those view definitions:

```
public interface IAppOnExitAware
{
    void SaveViewSettings();
}
```

And then have my views declared like:

```
public partial class ExistingOrderView : UserControl, IAppOnExitAware
```

Then in App, I want to override OnExit to iterate through all views.
And if its IAppOnExitAware - to call its SaveViewSettings().
Something like:

```
foreach(var v in COLLECTION)
{
    if(v is IAppOnExitAware)
    {
        ((IAppOnExitAware)v).SaveViewSettings();
    }
}
```

How can I get that COLLECTION of views in all modules of the catalog, to iterate through?

Update: each module registers views like

```
public class ModuleA : IModule
{
    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
    }

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Page01View, Page01ViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you register the views?

Comment: @mm8 I've updated my question, how views are registered

Comment: You should keep track of the registered views yourself. The container doesn't expose the type registrations in some nice way and even if it did, it doesn't keep track of the currently displayed views.